# Price calculation from CSV file - PHP/JS

Tags: php, csv

I'm looking for some advice on how to write a PHP script that will calculate the correct price from a CSV file containing height and width measurements and then return the correct price.

I would need to display 2 HTML select boxes allowing selection of the width and height sizes and then be able to use those values to calculate the correct price from the CSV file - an example being that if a size select of 914 x 762 was selected, I would be able to return the price of 23.05.

I've attached a screenshot of and example of the CSV file and have made the sizes (width/height) bold for examples sake.

I'm not looking for a complete solution, but a point in the right direction on how I can achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can I ask why you're not using a database for this?

Comment: I think using [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) would be a good place to start.

Comment: @BaineSumpin - I'm open to using a database for this. But the CSV may get updated on a regular basis and the database would then need to be updated too. It would be much a much easier business process just to upload a new/updated CSV to a folder and have the script work from that. Alternatively, I would need to write a script that processes the CSV to recreate the database table on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

Although I think you should use a database for this.  You can count the deliminators on the first row to the right dimension, then search for the line with the correct dimension and use the previous deliminator count to find your value.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of using a database - I had considered this already but it adds more work for me and for my clients business processes. I've managed to do this myself utilising the CSV file directly and have added my working code to my answer. Ps. It's 'delimiter', not 'deliminator' BTW ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I took on-board suggestions of using a database for this however, as my client already uses CSV files for their sizes/prices, this would just create another process for them. So I put together some code which works directly from the CSV file.

Here is my code below (albeit a little basic and messy, but it works!):

```
<?php

// Get CSV header
$ch = fopen("test.csv", "r");
$header_row = fgetcsv($ch);

// Get array of rows
$rows = array_map('str_getcsv', file('test.csv'));

// Remove first row (header row) as we already have this separately
unset( $rows[0] );
?>

<form action="" method="post" name="calc">

Width: <select name="width">

<?php
    // Remove first blank cell from $header
    unset( $header_row[0] );
    foreach ( $header_row as $key => $width ){
        echo '<option value="' . $key . '">' . $width . 'mm</option>';
    }
?>

</select>


Height: <select name="height">

<?php
    foreach ( $rows as $key => $row ){
        echo '<option value="' . $key . '">' . $row[0] . 'mm</option>';
    }
?>

</select>

<input type="submit" name="get-price" value="Get Price!">

</form>

<?php

if ( isset( $_POST['get-price'] ) ){
    $width = $_POST['width'];
    $height = $_POST['height'];
    echo 'Price: £' . $rows[$height][$width];
}

?>
```